# IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: {yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8032

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Hadoop 3.2.4 and hive 3.1.3 and single node setup

When I tried to run insert query in hive

I got this errors.

I have tried some of the Solutions provided on stack overflow but it's not working.

````
            java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your 
            configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:116)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:109)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:102)
             at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:475)
              at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.<init>(JobClient.java:454)
             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:381)
             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:149)
             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:205)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:97)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2664)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:2335)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:2011)```
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1709)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1703)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.run(ReExecDriver.java:157)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.run(ReExecDriver.java:218)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:239)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:188)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:402)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to use org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider due to error: 
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:148)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: {yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8032 (configuration property 'yarn.resourcemanager.address')
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:200)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf.YarnConfiguration.getSocketAddr(YarnConfiguration.java:4141)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.ClientRMProxy.getRMAddress(ClientRMProxy.java:90)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy.newProxyInstance(RMProxy.java:133)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy.createRMProxy(RMProxy.java:103)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.ClientRMProxy.createRMProxy(ClientRMProxy.java:72)
at
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.serviceStart(YarnClientImpl.java:233)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ResourceMgrDelegate.serviceStart(ResourceMgrDelegate.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop
````

Comment: what is your insert qry and how you are trying to insert - like using shell or using hue?

Comment: Your error is related to `yarn-site.xml`, and not exactly Hive setup. Did you try to test your YARN setup using `mapreduce-examples` JAR, for example? You should probably not have literal `{yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}` in the value, as the error seems to say

Comment: @KoushikRoy through hive shell and a simple insert query.

Comment: I was looking for how u r connecting to hive. It says host port unavailable. Can you share the shell command to connect and insert command.